# C++ sending keys to a window

Tags: c++, windows

I want to create a program which simulates key presses or just write a text to a specific application window.
This is what I've tried but it doesn't seem to work.

```
void MainWindow::on_startButton_clicked()
{
    HWND windowname = FindWindow(NULL, L"<mywindowname>");
    SendMessage(windowname, WM_SETTEXT, NULL, (LPARAM)"Window");
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You'll probably want that text to be a wide string, but unless that's your own window, you're probably better off with `SetWindowText`.

Comment: @chris does this change the window title? because thats not what i want

Comment: @Davlog: `WM_SETTEXT` is mostly the same... if you want to simulate keypresses you have to use `SendInput` or individual `WM_KEYDOWN`/`WM_KEYUP` (but if the application bypasses the normal key messages to get input they won't work).

Comment: See my answer here, which can easily be converted to c++: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41886193/1599699

Answer (score 0):

So I found out today that `SendMessage` will only send a single character (at least it's the solution for my problem). So for a string I have to do the following for each character in it.

```
QString string = "Hello";
foreach(QChar c, string){
  SendMessage(windowname, WM_KEYDOWN, (int)c-0x20, 0);
  SendMessage(windowname, WM_CHAR, (int)c-0x20, 0);
  SendMessage(windowname, WM_KEYUP, (int)c-0x20, 0);
}
```

[For more information about this function and deeper details on WM_KEY's etc. click here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646267%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_win32_Virtual_Key_Codes_Described)